# How to present apparent gap in employment CV, due to visiting research position that wasn’t formally employment?

Tags: cv, visiting

In between two postdocs, I spent four months as a fully-funded participant of a research “special programme”.  In practise, this was much like my other postdoc positions: it was full time work on the same sort of research, at a comparably prestigious academic institution, and the “stipend for living expenses” was in the ballpark of a postdoc salary.  However, it was not formally an employed position, from an administrative/legal point of view.

**How should I describe this, if at all, in the “Employment” section of my CV?**  The application I’m currently making prescribes the CV format fairly strictly; so I can certainly list this under the “research visits” in a later section, but I’m not sure what to do in the “employment” section. Listing this as employment doesn’t quite feel appropriate (since it wasn’t, formally); omitting it entirely gives an unexplained gap in my employment history (which, according to conventional wisdom, looks bad); presumably the right thing to do is to not include it in the main list, but add a short note explaining the gap; but I can’t find a good concise phrasing to describe this situation.

(In the past, I’ve avoided this issue by listing my employment history like “2012–14: Postdoc, University A.  2014–17: Postdoc, University B.”  But this particular application specifies that employment dates must include months, so I can’t sweep it under the rug again.)

Comment: I would say nobody cares if you got money and how much, only that you worked. Are the people there happy to recommend do? Did they see you as a "normal" worker? Do you have a "title" there?

Comment: Also, you got a stipend! Does it have a "good name"? You could mention that you worked there under this stipend.

Comment: Put it on your CV. Many positions are not technically ‘employment’ to avoid paying benefits. But a supported 4 month stint sounds a lot like a postdoc or visiting scientist gig, entirely normal for early career folks.